# New Vostro 3360 touchpad scroll

Tags: touchpad

I have purchased one Vostro 3360 that appears to be supported by [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201203-10658/).

I have problems with Ethernet ([I solved with alx drivers](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/alx)) and touchpad Alps (scroll not working) after install Ubuntu 12.04. (Same with Debian Testing and Ubuntu 12.10 beta 1)

I can't select touchpad options in GNOME and  Touchpad appears as PS/2 Mouse with xinput --list.

I found information in several bug reports but nothing works.

[psmouse solution][3] with this I can select Touchpad settings but scroll is still not working.

Oneiric packages from DELL http://wielki.tk/vostro/ with this everything works but the mousepad response is very bad and sometimes all the machine hangs completely)

I only installed: http://wielki.tk/vostro/debs/glidepoint_3.6-10_amd64.deb

[3]: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php? t=1887683&page=2

Comment: Welcome to the club. I have my laptop for 3 months now and I still haven't found a good driver for the ALPS touchpad.

Comment: With Oneiric packages I have a "good" experience with touchpad. But scroll response is still bad....

Comment: Is this still reproducible?

Answer (score 0):

I use Dell Vostro 1510. I once had problem with the Touchpad scroll (which stopped working) when I updated the Dell Touchpad. After the update, the Dell Touchpad changed to Synaptics PS/2 Port Touchpad.

This problem was solved thus: at the Start menu, click on **Control Panel**, in **Device Manager**, click on the **Update Device Drivers**, expand the tab named **Mice and other Pointing Devices** and *double-click* on **Synaptics PS/2 Port Touchpad**. At the Dell Touchpad Properties Dialog box that comes up, click on the **Drivers** tab and then click on **Roll Back Drivers**. Give it time to roll back to the original Dell Touchpad. Then restart and enjoy your Touchpad Scroll.

The steps are:

> **Start menu → Control Panel → Update Device Drivers → Synaptics PS/2 Port Touchpad → Roll Back Drivers (under drivers tab)**

Comment: This is a windows solution

Answer (score -1):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/606238

Tomorrow i will check last posts solution(alps.c V6).. it seems that could be solved....

Answer (score -1):

see **post-factum** answer here : 
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=144118&p=1

by the way to copy the folder you download to /usr/src you must be root:
sudo su -
then to copy go to the folder and type:
cp -R psmouse-alps-dst-1.2/ /usr/src/

Comment: In case the link you provided does actually have the answer to the question, please quote the relevant part here.